# Bitronix + Spring tests + Different spring profiles

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-test, bitronix

I have several tests which all extends the same root test which define the Spring test application context. One of my test use a different profile so I have annotated the child class with `@ActiveProfiles("specialTestProfile")`, this profile create a special mock bean which is injected in the context. I want to clear my context before and after executing this test, but I didn't find the correct way to do it. I know that the Spring test framework does some context caching and that in my case I should have two different context and it should not be necessary to reload the context but it is not working because of bitronix which generate this strange error if I don't clean the context:

```
    Caused by: bitronix.tm.resource.ResourceConfigurationException: cannot create JDBC datasource named unittestdb
    at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource.init(PoolingDataSource.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor404.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1608)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: resource with uniqueName 'unittestdb' has already been registered
    at bitronix.tm.resource.ResourceRegistrar.register(ResourceRegistrar.java:55)
    at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource.buildXAPool(PoolingDataSource.java:68)
at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource.init(PoolingDataSource.java:53)
... 68 more
```

Even if I reload the context for each test class (by annotating my parent class with `@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)`, I still get the error above at some point... do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your exact configuration for the `PoolingDataSource`, I cannot know exactly how to solve your issue.

However, it appears that you can likely solve this issue by creating your `PoolingDataSource` with a unique name by invoking the `setUniqueName()` method (in an `@Bean` method if you're using Java config) or by setting the `uniqueName` property (if you're using XML config). How you generate the unique name depends on the configuration style you are using.

If you do not set a unique name for each `ApplicationContext` that creates the `PoolingDataSource` bean, you will continue to see the exception telling you that a second pool cannot be created with the "unittestdb" name since it already exists. The reason is that the `init()` method in `PoolingDataSource` delegates to `ManagementRegistrar.register()` which registers an `MBean` under the *unique name*, and the same `MBeanServer` is used for all tests within the same JVM process (i.e., for all tests in your suite).

Instead of generating a unique pool name per application context, another option might be to disable the use of JMX by setting the `bitronix.tm.disableJmx` property to `false`. Consult the `isDisableJmx()` and `setDisableJmx()` methods in `bitronix.tm.Configuration` for details.

Comment: thx for your answer I'll try the disableJmx option, because I alredy tried the uniqueName solution but I get another error saying that I cannot register two different XA datasources. I'll let you know!